# How do I easily bookmark sites on delicious.com?

Tags: bookmarks

On my desktop I often use delicious.com chrome plugin to save bookmarks to interesting sites. Quite often I also want to save interesting sites to delicious.com when browsing on Android browser.

What is the best way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a dedicated [Android app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.delicious) available now for Delicious from AVOS.

Comment: Does it have the feature the questioner wants: is it easy to save a site to Delicious from the browser?

Comment: Link to Official Delicious Apps from AVOS
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.delicious

Comment: I've installed this Delicious app, version from 14 January 2014. The previous app I used Andricious haven't been updated since 2012. Hence marked this Delicous app as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

Install [DeliciousDroid](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.deliciousdroid), it will add an entry in the `share` menu of your browser where you can bookmark the current page and define tags for it and so on.

Edit: I tried some different tools (don't remember wich, sorry) some time ago and this one was the best in my opinion. Also I defined a tag called `mobile-home` and pointed my browser's homepage to the list of so-tagged bookmarks.

Comment: Is there no link to post to delicious on the page you want to save or am I misunderstanding you?

Comment: TQ Silas. How does DeliciousDroid compares with [Andricious](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.sherbert.delicious)? I'm trying the latter first, since it seems more popular.

Comment: sabre23t: Don't know why, but Andricious is not available for my device (Galaxy S2 running 2.3.5), so what I'm writing may be wrong. As far as I understand Andricious is only a bookmark browser and manager for android (plus widget) but not a browser extension to bookmark pages. And there seems to be a bug that it  deletes assigned tags on edit (see market comments).

Comment: Thanks for the response, Silas. So far Andricious works okay for me (Samsung Galaxy S2 running 2.3.3). No tags deleted on my delicious bookmarks page. However, DeliciousDroid is still in my todo list, just in case. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can also try [Droidicious](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aor.droidicious.free&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5hb3IuZHJvaWRpY2lvdXMuZnJlZSJd). It works fine for me.